# Mustache Syntax: Conditionally Print HTML

Tags: html, json, mustache

I have a JSON of the form:

```
{
  "repo": [
    { "type": "A" },
    { "type": "B" },
    { "type": "B" },
    { "type": "C" }
  ]
}
```

Which I am printing in HTML using the Mustache Syntax as below

```
{{#repo}}
  {{type}}
{{/repo}}
```

Now, based on type either being A,B or C I need to print certain words conditionally with the given mapping:

```
"A" = "Small"
"B" = "Medium"
"C" = "Big"
```

Is there any way I can do this with Mustache?

```
var txt = '{"repo": [{ "type": "A" },{ "type": "B" },{ "type": "B" },{ "type": "C" }],"typeMapped":{},"types": {"A": "Small",   "B": "Medium","C": "Big"}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(txt);

obj.typeMapped = function () {
    return obj.types[obj.type] || "";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```js
{
  "repo": [
    { "type": "A" },
    { "type": "B" },
    { "type": "B" },
    { "type": "C" }
  ], 
  "typeMapped": function () {
    return this.types[this.type] || "";
  }, 
  "types": {
    "A": "Small",
    "B": "Medium",
    "C": "Big"
  }
}
```

```html
{{#repo}}
  {{type}}: {{typeMapped}}
{{/repo}}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but this is an invalid json as per https://mustache.github.io/#demo

Comment: You need to JSON.parse your JSON, then add typemapped and types. Ofc you cannot have a function in JSON, but that is too basic to answer here.

Comment: I came up something in JS for that, edited the question

Comment: You forgot to also add `types`.